# RegExp Get substring between tabs and include a special char

Tags: c#, .net, regex, vb.net

I'm here with a problem of a simple RegExp.
I want to retrieve from a specific string all substrings that accomplish with the following rules:
1. The values are between TABs.
2. Also include double quotes.

How can I do that?

I found the way to get the values between TABs, but I cannot figure out how include the double quotes validation.

```
'get the text from clipboard
Dim stringInClipboard As String = ClipboardGet()

Dim vRegExMatch As System.Text.RegularExpressions.MatchCollection = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Matches(stringInClipboard, "\t[^\t\\]*(?:\\.[^\t\\]*)*\t")
```

Example:

```
{Tab} Comment 1 {Tab}
{Tab} Comment 2 {Tab}
{Tab} Long comment text.

some text
.
"<--Double quotes!!!
.
{Tab}
{Tab} Comment 4 {Tab}
```

Basically, I want retrieve:

```
Long comment text.   
some text
.
"<--Double quotes!!!
.
```

Comment: please clarify, is it value surrounded by \t OR by "", or is it more like \t"value"\t ?

Comment: `\tnot all "matches\twill" occur\t`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer thanks to @kabb!

I modified a little the RegEx:

```
(?s)\t(?=[^\t]*[""]+)[^\t]*[\t]{1}
```

Here is the live-test:
http://regex101.com/r/rM6hC3

[image: RegEx]

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
(?s)\t(?=[^\t]*?").*?\t
```

- `(?s)` makes it so that the dot character matches new lines, which your example includes.
- `\t` checks to see if the string starts with a tab
- `(?=[^\t]*?")` looks ahead to see if there are any double quotes BEFORE the next tab is encountered
- `.*\t` matches all of the characters up until the next tab, if the look ahead suceeded

Comment: If you take me example and use your RegEx in the link; you will see the comment 4 is included into the result: http://regex101.com/

Comment: @MiBol Are you trying to literally use the word {tab}? Because my example only works for actual tabs...

Comment: No; see the picture (BTW thanks for your time!): https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-Eiv_ORMfR1Y/Uxqhui8nasI/AAAAAAAABWk/WdPQJZgiB6U/w930-h333-no/RegEx.png